# Как реализовать сортировку(фильтрацию) коллекции в контроллере на Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Как реализовать простой фильтер с помощью input уже хорошо известно, а вот как делать фильтрацию данных в контроллере(или в директиве), а не на view пока не знаю.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.fname">
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
```

Как перенести код выше в контроллер или директиву?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно зачем это выносить в контроллер, специально для этого придумали фильтры.

Фильтр можно написать свой.
Например, такой фильтр отображает в представлении только строки, начинающиеся с литеры `A`:

```
.filter("myFilter", function() {
    return function(input) {
        var out = [];
        for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++)
            if(input[i].length && input[i][0] == 'A')
                out.push(input);
        return out;
    }
});
```

Если делать в контроллере, то придётся создавать дополнительное поле в `$scope` (в противном случае мы потеряем данные, не прошедшие фильтр).

```
$scope.data = [ ... ]; //наши данные
$scope.filtered_data = a.filter(function(item) {
    if(item.length && item[0] == 'A') return true;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда реализовать поиск с помошью фильтра? Я имею ввиду свой фильтер.  Не понимаю как связать данные..

Comment: @MaximCherevatov, не понял вопроса. Пример создания своего фильтра я написал.

Comment: ну есть в view поле для поиска значений(в моем примере). Поиск в представлениях - плохой тон, и серьезная нагрузка если есть большое количество элемент. Вот я и спрашиваю как перенести процесс поиска с представления в контроллер, фильтер, директиву и тд.

Comment: @MaximCherevatov Фильтрация и так выполняется в фильтрах и директивах. `ng-model` - это обычная директива. Смысл переносить это в другую директиву?